# Hide html element with same data in ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a array of task in which there are two duplicate departments, but i dont want to show the second duplicate record in ng-repeat, but only for the first record i want to show even if it is duplicate.
Here is my code, can anyone tell me where i'm going wrong.

```
<tr ng-repeat="t in item.requisitionTask track by t.id">
<td>
<div ng-hide="!$first ? item.requisitionTask[$index-1].department.departmentCode==$index.department.departmentCode : false">
{{t.department.departmentName}}</div>
</td>
```

Comment: `$index.department.departmentCode` - I dont think the `$index` variable has properties like that, it's simply a number.

Comment: Whenever you see a huge condition like this, it SCREAMS to be put into a scoped function returning true/false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by targeting the data particularly.

```
<td><div ng-hide="!$first ? item.requisitionTask[$index-1].department.departmentCode==item.requisitionTask[$index].department.departmentCode : false">
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you want to hide data if the previous item contains the same `departmentCode` as your current item.  As mentioned in my comment, you should move this logic into a function on your controller's scope.

```
<tr ng-repeat="t in item.requisitionTask track by t.id">
  <td>
    <div ng-hide="isNotFirstOrSameCodeAsPrevious($index)">
        {{t.department.departmentName}}
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

In your controller:

```
function isNotFirstOrSameCodeAsPrevious($index) {
    if ($index === 0) return false;

    return item.requisitionTask[$index - 1].department.departmentCode ===
        item.requisitionTask[$index].department.departmentCode; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually i wasn't targeting $index particularly as i did before comparing. your ans also seams some sort of solution.

Comment: @RohanSampat I've provided the same answer as yours :).  The logic is the same.  The difference is that you can't step through your expression but you CAN step through my answer, which makes it far easier to troubleshoot and maintain.  In addition, I think it's more readable.